# How To Import Multiple Grafana Dashbords via A Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, dashboard, helm3, grafana-dashboard

Is there a way to install multiple Grafana dashboards into the same folder via Helm?

I have created a configMap

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboards
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  kubernetes.json: |
{{ .Files.Get "dashboards/kubernetes-cluster.json" | indent 4 }}
```

And also created a dashbordProvider and dashboardConfigMap for it.

```
dashboardProviders:
 dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'monitoring'
     orgId: 1
     folder: "monitoring"
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/monitoring
```

```
dashboardsConfigMaps:
 monitoring: "grafana-dashboards"
```

However, I want to add an additional dashboard into the same `monitoring` folder.

I've tried importing the json via the Grafana UI, and it works just fine, but I would like to persist it in code.

So I've created a new configmap.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: persistent-volumes
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  kubernetes.json: |
{{ .Files.Get "dashboards/persistent-volumes.json" | indent 4 }}
```

And also created a new dashboardProviders section and dashbordConfigMap

```
dashboardProviders:
 dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'monitoring'
     orgId: 1
     folder: "monitoring"
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/monitoring
   - name: 'pvc'
     orgId: 1
     folder: "monitoring"
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/monitoring
```

```
dashboardsConfigMaps:
 monitoring: "grafana-dashboards"
 pvc: "persistent-volumes"
```

But when I log into Grafana, I see a `pvc` folder but no dashboard in it.

What I want to do is to create this new dashboard inside the `monitoring` folder. The same way I'm able to do in the UI

Comment: https://github.com/esnet/gdg is a nice helper for this use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config looks about right.

Have you tried changing the path for the `pvc` provider to `path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pvc`

So it looks like this.

```
dashboardProviders:
 dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'monitoring'
     orgId: 1
     folder: "monitoring"
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/monitoring
   - name: 'pvc'
     orgId: 1
     folder: "monitoring"
     type: file
     disableDeletion: false
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pvc
```

Instead of what you have at the moment.